# Is it safe for a man standing inside a Faraday cage to touch it from inside

Tags: electricity, electric-current, conductors

Will a man get electrocuted if he touches a Faraday cage from inside when a high potential difference is developed between a Faraday cage and some other source?
If yes then how a person wearing Faraday suits is safe while maintaining high voltage lines?

Answer (score 3):

The amount of "safeness" depends on the material of the cage.

The cage and the man are parallel resistors, right?

So, what happens when you put in parallel a very low resistor to a very high resistor? The overall resistance is closer to the low resistor, and most current flows from there. Very little current passes from the high resistor.

Example: If faraday cage is made from copper, the man is fine.
If faraday cage is made from wet wood and the man is also wet. Then, man is probably doomed.

Answer (score 0):

I would be hesitant, but these Tesla-coil-show performers seem to be fine in their Faraday suits:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTkjgBRiCsE